# C# - Excel - DisplayFormat - Get formatting details

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk, closedxml

I'm trying to get Excel cell formatting as users sees it. In VBA or the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel this is done via the [DisplayFormat API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.displayformat?view=excel-pia). But I can't use interop or VBA on the prod server.. Is there any way to access this information using OpenXML or ClosedXML please?

Reason I'm asking is I'm trying create HTML tables from the sheets including formatting, especially whatever conditional formatting does to the cells. Using `cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color` returns Transparent, as it should, the formatting is not actually set in the cell details. Thank you!

Comment: You can check if the cell has conditional formatting using Interop and then check which condition is true. That ways you can get the formatting details.

Comment: Would you please elaborate on how to check if a given condition is met on an individual cell? That would be great. My goal is to not use the interop, because I don't want to have Office installed on server..

Comment: If you do not want to use Interop then my suggestion will not help

Comment: ClosedXml has APIs for creating [ConditionalFormatting](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/develop/ClosedXML.Examples/ConditionalFormatting/ConditionalFormatting.cs), but there doesn't seem to be anything that will evaluate them against the cell content (to get the rendered result).